# Prevent CSS Flex From Stretching on Both Axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to prevent stretching on both axis of CSS Flex? In the example below, I want the the option and box layers to adjust to the width and height of the children. Additionally, I want the box to be in the middle of the page.

I am aware of flex-grow and basis, but my understanding is it only manages the space of the main axis.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: center;
}

.option {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.img-container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <label class="option">
            Option 1
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=0.752xw:1.00xh;0.175xw,0&resize=640:*" />
            </div>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            Option 2
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=0.752xw:1.00xh;0.175xw,0&resize=640:*" />
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the red container box to not be stretched? Have you tried `display: inline-flex`? Flex by default acts as `display: block` and takes up the full width.

Comment: I tried that but I'm seeing it stretch, all it did was much the children to the left. Which layer should it be on?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by this? "I want the the option and box layers to adjust to the width and height of the children"